# I [haven't]/[hadn't] seen him for a long time so I [have] decided

Tags: grammaticality

CONTEXT:

John is my friend. I'm in his house right now (we've been talking for about 20 minutes). My other friend calls me and asks me: "Where are you?" I say: "I'm in John's house at the moment." Then he says: "Why are you there?" I reply to him with one of the sentences below.

SENTENCES:

1. I **hadn't seen** him for a long time, so I **decided** to pay him a visit. That's why I'm here in his house.
2. I **haven't seen** him for a long time, so I **have decided** to pay him a visit. That's why I'm here in his house.

QUESTION:

Which of the above sentences should be used in the context given? I'm wondering about the tenses in bold.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Please explain what you think would be correct and why do you have doubts. Otherwise it will look like a homework question, and this site does not provide such service.

Answer (score 0):

Either form might be used. Either would be natural and might be used by a fluent speaker, and both would be easily understood by a fluent speaker.

Form 1 emphasizes the past moment when the decision to visit John was made. Form 2 emphasizes the (past but recent) decision and the current visit as parts of a single process. Even that difference is a nuance, and either might be used with little or no intention of variation of meaning.